# How to get the right result for average weekdays average saturdays and average sundays in ssrs reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I have one table which contains entered calls for employees.Grouped by hour and date.

I have column Average Weekdays,which should returns me the average value for weekdays without Saturday and Sunday.

I use this expression :

```
=iif(weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<>6 and 7,avg(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value),0)
```

------<>6 and 7 not in Saturday and Sunday,but doesn't work in this case. --------

I understand that i should received the result average for weekdays,but my report returns me result with Saturdays and Sundays.

In other expression the things are similarly.(Average Saturdays and Average Sundays).

`=iif(weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)=6,avg(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value),0)`  ---6 is saturday ---

`=iif(weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)=7,avg(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value),0)`  ---6 is sunday---

When am i wrong ?

Expected results in RED - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xUGI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your scenario on my local machine.

First you have to understand what your saturday and sunday returns. In my case Sunday is 1 and Saturday is 7.

Below is how I get average for weekday and for weekend.

Expression for weekday to get data.

```
=IIF(Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)<>7 and Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)<>1, Fields!CallData.Value,0)
```

and for average of weekday

```
=Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)<>7 and Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)<>1, Fields!CallData.Value,0))/countRows()
```

Same way for weekend

```
=IIF(Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)=7 and Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)=1, Fields!CallData.Value,0)
```

and for average of weekday

```
=Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)=7 and Weekday(Fields!Date.Value)=1, Fields!CallData.Value,0))/countRows()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.You helped me with the first step and now everything is okey.Have a nice day!